# Why SVC repeates it parameter in the output

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

My aim is to classify the extracted features from CNN using support vector machine.

Extracted features have a shape (2186, 128), which is an np array saved in X_tr.

Y has the shape (2186,) an array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])

Applying these to SVC.

*Input:*

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

*Output:*

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

Why is it giving parameters as output instead of classification?

Comment: Calling `fit()` trains the estimator and then returns a trained SVC back. You need to use this trained SVC to predict new data, which you are not doing anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, is this mean that my SVC is trained and I can use it to predict the test data?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to see? You have trained the classifier on your training data and now you need to evaluate the classifier on your test data. In scikit-learn, you train a classifier using:

`clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`

and you make a prediction with the trained classifier using something like:

`predictions = clf.predict(X_test)`

Comment: Thanks, I was confused that my SVC is trained or not. The output I got means that the model is trained. Now I can use this trained model to predict the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y)
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

wont give any output.
If you want to test classification and prediction then use

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
            decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
                max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
                    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
clf.fit(X_train, y)
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print pred
```

---

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
               decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
               max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
               tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

In SVC C, cache_size, class_weight etc. these are the parameters which SVC takes. These parameters you can use for tuning like you want to use 'linear' or 'rbf' kernel with 'C:1000'.
For more info please check: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html